# filemanager.createFileAtPath works not correctly

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsfilemanager

I try to create a PLIST-File with the `NSFileManager` and the method `createFileAtPath`. In the end, the file was created, it has the size of 0 Bytes, and i even can see the specific PLIST-Icon for that file in the Finder.
But when i want to open it (for example with Xcode) it says:`The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format`.
I want to write to this file but when its not in the correct format i can't do this.

There is something wrong with the File-creation but i don't know what it is.
I hope you can help me with this.
Here is my code:

```
pListPath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: reportsPath.path!).URLByAppendingPathComponent("myReports.plist", isDirectory: false)

                let data: NSData = NSData()
                var isDir: ObjCBool = false

                if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(pListPath.path!, isDirectory: &isDir)
                    {
                        print("File already exits")
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        let success = fileManager.createFileAtPath(pListPath.path!, contents: data, attributes: nil)

                        print("Was file created?: \(success)")
                        print("plistPath: \(pListPath)")
                    }
```

reports.path = `.../UserDir/.../Documents/Reports`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: In iOS you always have to create a reference to the folder `Documents` with `NSURL` or `NSFileManager`. Did you do that?

Comment: I created the reference like this. i copied it from from another post here: `let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filemanager.createFileAtPath` works absolutely correctly,
but you're creating an empty file by writing an empty `NSData` object to disk.
`NSData` objects are not implicitly serialized to a property list.

Either use the `NSPropertyListSerialization` class or – simpler - write an empty dictionary to disk.

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary()
let success = dictionary.writeToURL(pListPath, atomically: true)
print("Was file created?: \(success)")
print("plistPath: \(pListPath)")
```

PS: you don't need to create an URL from an URL

```
pListPath = reportsPath.URLByAppendingPathComponent("myReports.plist", isDirectory: false)
```

but I recommend to use more descriptive variable names to distinguish `String` paths and `NSURL` e.g. `pListURL` and `reportsURL`